# weird artifacting in embedded view

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to embed Google maps' street view on my website, but something weird shows up on the result:

http://www.biei.us/photography/autorotate/

as you see, the zoom slider and google logo has a white background. How do i fix this?

this is the code I use:
http://www.biei.us/photography/wp-content/themes/galleria-v2/autorotate/pano01.js

and this is how i embed it:
(in header)

(in body)

Any help is appreciated,

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

For me there is also a white border for the tiles.

There are `padding`,'background'-and `border`-settings for `img` that also have been applied to the images of the panorama.

Use this CSS to override it:

```
#pano img{padding:0 !important;border:none !important;background:none;}
```